# How to submit input to set variable?

Tags: jquery, json, api

I have a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/2059/) that isn't quite working due to the input field not communicating to the google API. How to get this to work?

```
var enteredAddress = $('#entered-address').val();
var geocodingAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + enteredAddress + " Boise ID&sensor=true";

$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the results array
    var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;  
    var latitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;    
    var longitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    // Set text in html
    $('#address').text(address);
    $('#latitude').text(latitude);
    $('#longitude').text(longitude);
});
```

Comment: It looks like you need some sort of event handler. When do you want the geocoding to happen? Upon form submission? Upon the click of a button?

Comment: Upon the click of a button would be fine.

Comment: What about the spaces in the URL in the `Boise ID&`?

Comment: removed thanks and help request. Good question. Please avoid adding thanks and help to questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your URL `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps...` is using the HTTP protocol, but JSFiddle uses the HTTPS protocol. AJAX requests must use the same protocol, or else it's a security violation!

To do a protocol-relative URL, replace `http://` in the Google Maps URL with just `//`.

Second, you don't have a button to click to get it working! How do you expect it to work?

Third, your Google Maps URL has `address= Boise ID`, which has two spaces. Replace it with `%20Boise%20ID`.

Finally, you don't even need that `Boise ID` thing at all! Remove it! If you keep it, the location will always be Boise, ID, and nothing else will work if the user types in a location.